# Unable to connect to https://repo.maven.apache.org using cmd or IDE

Tags: maven, networking, maven-2, maven-plugin, firewall

I am trying to clean build my project using maven.
But when i do, i get this error[image]

But, i am able to open the link through my browser.

Comment: Proxy/Firewall configuration?

Comment: @khmarbaise I have seen in proxy settings in internet explorer. But, there was no proxy setup.

Comment: You need to set them in settings.xml for Maven not for your browser etc. Do you have an corporate repository manager.

Comment: @khmarbaise No, we dont have any repository manager.

Comment: That's bad. Than you have to configure proxy corretly in your settings.xml...I can recommend to setup a repository which handles those things.